# How to make an object disposable in Dart?

Tags: dart, inheritance, disposable

I have an abstract class named `AbstractFoo` and its implementation, `Foo`. `Foo` also implements an interface `Bar`. I would like to make `Foo` disposable so I assume that I need to implement [Disposable](https://pub.dev/documentation/w_common/latest/disposable/Disposable-class.html) class but I am getting an error

> Classes and mixins can only implement other classes and mixins

I tried to make `AbstractFoo` implement `Disposable` but I get the same error. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

There is no automatic disposal system built into Dart. You are referencing the [w_common package](https://pub.dev/packages/w_common).

According to the page you linked, you will need to define classes you want to be disposed something like this:

```dart
class MyDisposable extends Object with Disposable {
   MyDisposable() {
     var thing = new ThingThatRequiresCleanup();
     getManagedDisposer(() {
       thing.cleanUp();
       return new Future(() {});
     });
   }
 }
```

For more specific help, please edit your question to include code.

Comment: I've been working so much I haven't event noticed that I've been referencing that package. Thanks